# Validate Firebase User with Java (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to validate my user in backend with firebaseAuth, I followed the firebase documentation to connect here https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and the token validation from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

following these articles I've copied this code:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()).build();

        FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        String token = "my_token";

        FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp).verifyIdToken(token);
        String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
```

I think theoretically this should work, but when I try to call verifyIdToken it's returning IllegalArgumentException, in the documentation is saying this exception is returned when 'the token is null, empty, or if the FirebaseApp instance does not have a project ID associated with it.'
Well.. my token is not null or empty, so I tried looking for the second option.

In my credentials I've downloaded the private key from my project and set the environment variable if I debug my FirebaseApp I can see the projectId in FirebaseApp -> options -> credentials -> projectId, I can also see the other values from my json set in the environment, but I notice that FirebaseApp -> options -> projectId was null

after debugging for a while I tried to manually set the project Id with this code:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setProjectId("my_project_id")
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()).build();
```

Now the FirebaseApp -> options -> projectId has the value of my projectId, but the same error is happening

Does anyone have some idea of what it could be?

Comment: I'm not clear why you would think that the string "my_token" is a valid Firebase Auth token.  You can't invent your own tokens - they can only come from Firebase client apps.

Comment: It's not the token I used, I'm using the token coming from mobile, but for security reason, I'm not putting it here, and even if the token was wrong I think the verifyIdToken is supposed to return FirebaseAuthException

Comment: the same in project_id, I used my real projectId in the real code

Comment: @LuizWalber your code looks valid. Can you add stacktrace to your question? Also, are you 100% sure that in runtime your token string is not null or empty?

Comment: Without seeing the token for ourselves, or even how you obtain it and pass it from the client app, it's hard to say if you are actually passing a valid token value.

Comment: The runtime values are ok I think
[link](https://prnt.sc/un6g4c)

the stack trace is: [link](https://prnt.sc/un6hgm)

Comment: the real token is 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFlNjYzOGY4NDlkODVhNWVkMGQ1M2NkNDI1MzE0Y2Q1MGYwYjY1YWUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ'

Comment: I'm recovering it with flutter using:

final FirebaseUser test = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final idtoken = await test.getIdToken();

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase token was wrong, I've copied and pasted it but only the first part got copied, I've used the correct token and everything works fine now, thanks to everyone for the attention